# How to reduced content of item in one field OOB

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

We have two lists, "Opening project" list and "Closing project" list. When the project is finished (no more continue), its going to be closed and will call the closed project list.

I have a `report` field (multi line text) under closed project list. , which contains important information (more than 50 lines). I want to reduce some of the content in that field without deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated Columns can't handle complex Fieldtypes like Multi-Line, so your only options is

- a Scripting solution (back-end Powershell/CSOM/PnP or Front-end JavaScript) that reads the Field contents and rewrites it
- A workflow that rewrites the Multi-line

Comment: Thanks Danny ! Do you have a workflow that rewrite the multi-line ? appreciated

Comment: No,. you have to write it yourself.. SPD workfows can't easily be transferred/copy-pasted